# Can i check emulator is running and one specific application is insatlled in emulator or not?

Tags: unit-testing, android-emulator, android-testing, appium

I am new at mobile automation testing and now i want to create a one type of framework for android application testing that in before method it will check for if emualtor is ruuning or not? if not then launch the emulator and second specific application is installed or not(example: facebook) if facebook is installed then launch that application.
I am using appium for testing. Can any one suggest me what shuold i have to do?
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

First of all appium cannot automate pre-installed apps from play stores. You should have a ".apk" file to install it.

Secondly, appium cannot automate bringing up of emulator, however a way to do it is through the use of script of adb commands.Check through the adb command if any device is active

> adb devices

If it is not then you can start your emulator using the emulator commands of adb.

For complete adb commands reference.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html.

Lastly you can use different modes of appium like "--full-reset" for re-installing the app even if it is pre-installed or simple "appium" will start the ".apk" which was once installed by it.

Check all the modes here - "github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/server-args.md"

For other basic queries, visit - https://github.com/appium/training